# Get an image from the media library. Struggling with the code?

Tags: attachments, images, media-library

Struggling with this code, the conditions work, the only way I can get the wp_get_attachment_url is to loop through it but then this outputs as many images from the media library and I only want one?

```
  <div class="tvimage">
  <?php
    if ($imgurlbase != '' ) { ?>

    <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/timthumb.php?src=<?php echo $imgurlbase . $imgfromtv; ?>&h=62&w=75" alt="<?php echo $programme; ?>">

            <?php } elseif ($imgurlbase == '' ) { ?>

            <?php
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'post_status' => null,
        'post_parent' => null,
        ); 
    $attachments = get_posts( $args );


                foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {

                    if ($attachment->post_title == $programme) {
                            echo wp_get_attachment_url($attachment->ID);
                        }
                    else {
                    echo '<img src="';
                    echo bloginfo('template_url');
                    echo '/images/nontvimg.jpg" alt="no tv image" />';
                    }

                }


    ?>



            <?php } ?>


</div>
```

Comment: Why are you using the template URL if the image is in the media library? Uploaded items are stored in the uploads directory, which is typically at `wp-content/uploads/`.. Additionally `-1` in the numberposts arg is setting that query to unlimited, drop the minus(to set to 1).

Comment: because the first image is a custom field and is also run through a script, I need to run through all the images to find a match for $programme but I only want to output one

Comment: Like i said, change the `-1` to a `1` and you'll get only one image back, not mountains (minus one means no limit).

Comment: @erichmond: I think you need to provide a bit more context to what you want to achieve. What do you mean by you only want one? You're clearly generating output for every iteration of your loop. Also, what's in `$programme`? And...do you maybe only want the images attached to the current post that match `$programme`? It's just not quite clear what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @t31os: No, he can't do that, he's trying to find the attachment by its title...unless there's a query arg for that?

Comment: Can't limit it to 1 result? Erm... that's what the user is asking for and what `numberposts` controls.

Comment: the post has a custom field for an image, so:
if it exists use it,
if not check the image library for a match on the title
if not use a generic image

Comment: Yes sorry, i should of read the previous comments more carefully. Try using `'s' => 'name to search for'` or `'name' => 'some name'` inside your args array.

Comment: is there a way of just getting the url and not looping through with a foreach ?

Comment: If you know the ID yes, if not you'll need some sort of lookup query to figure out which attachments belong to a/the given post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to exit the loop after you find an attachment, use `break`.

```
 // Define $programme and pull up $attachments as above
 $attachment_url = '';
 foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
     if ($attachment->post_title == $programme) {
         $attachment_url = wp_get_attachment_url($attachment->ID);
         break;
     }
 }

 if ( $attachment_url ) {
     echo $attachment_url;
 } else {
     echo '/images/nontvimg.jpg';
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

Sorted this is the new code:

```
<?php
            if ($imgurlbase != '' ) { ?>

            <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/timthumb.php?src=<?php echo $imgurlbase . $imgfromtv; ?>&h=62&w=75" alt="<?php echo $programme; ?>">

            <?php } elseif ($imgurlbase == '' ) { ?>

                <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/timthumb.php?src=<?php
                $args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'attachment',
                    'numberposts' => -1,
                    'post_title' => $programme
                    ); 
                $attachments = get_posts( $args );

                $found = 0;
                foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
                   if ($attachment->post_title == $programme) {
                      echo wp_get_attachment_url($attachment->ID);
                      ++$found;
                   }
                }
                if (!$found) {
                   echo '/images/nontvimg.jpg';
                }

                ?>&h=62&w=75">


            <?php } ?>
```

Comment: How is `$programme` defined? And please, stop posting answers as updates, this is not how Stackoverflow/StackExchange sites operate, unless you're providing the solution/answer to your own question. Please add any updates or new code samples to the original question.